# Direct image upload to cloudinary using axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, cloudinary

I'm having a strange problem where the upload function return a 400 error while with the same code in another component, it works like a charm

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        var url = "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/my_image_server/image/upload";
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", this.state.img);
        formData.append("upload_preset", "the_correct_preset"); 
        formData.append("api_key", "the_correct_key");
        formData.append("timestamp", (Date.now() / 1000) | 0);
        return axios.post(url, formData, {
            headers: {
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log("There has been ERROR: " + err))
```

As i have mentioned above, this is the same exact copy & paste code in another component which works flawlessly. Can you guys please help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi have you checked each value that you provide to the body of your request? e.g `this.state.img`'s value.

Comment: omg that was the problem, how careless of me, thanks alot!

Comment: dude, you saved my day, i can't believe i've spent days banging my head without thinking of this in the first place! You should write the answer and get some stack points, you earned it!

Comment: Ehe I'm glad it helped you, I will put that in an answer thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

400 happens when the syntax of the request isn't what is expected.

Have you checked each value that you provide to the body of your request? e.g `this.state.img`'s value.